# What is a good synonym for “appointment”? Is “date” one of them?

Tags: synonyms, dates, german

**TL;DR:**

- **If I use “date” for “appointment”, is it unmistakably understood?**
- **If not, is there a shorter word for “appointment”?**

---

In German, there’s *Termin*, from Latin *terminus* (“boundary, limit”), for which there is no obvious English cognate. This German substantive can mean anything of the following:

- “appointment”, as in *doctor’s appointment*
- “meeting”, as in *statutory conference*
- “date”, as in *future arrangement* or *dutiful point in time*
- “deadline”, as in *closing date*

In these cases, *Termin* is well understood and of handy length. However, *Termin* doesn’t mean “(calendar) date” in general, and neither does “appointment”. On the other hand, “calendar date” translates to *Datum*, which in turn is cognate to “date”, thus my uncertainty.

I’m afraid that “making/having a *date* with so.” sounds rather private (i.e. non-platonic) than professional, even if it refers to a “scheduled date”.

I’m looking for a shorter synonym for “appointment”, with generic emphasis on “future due date”, but less specific than “deadline”. Is “date” generally understood as-such? Is there any alternative more concise than “assignment”?

---

Some examples of potential use:

- *I need to have those <del>appointments</del> conducted.*
- *You have to make <del>an appointment</del> at the doctor’s.*
- *We’ll meet at the business <del>appointment</del>.*
- *When would you like to have <del>an appointment</del>?*

I don’t think those struck through parts can be properly replaced with “date” while retaining their original meaning. There might simply be no (short) alternative to “appointment”. Is there?

Comment: Did you look at a thesaurus? There were several options I found when I looked...

Comment: @Laurel: That’s self-evident. I didn’t looked at one, but several thesauri. As you can see in the question’s text, I already stated some synonyms and my concerns regarding them. If you got something to share, tell us—ideally in an answer—those “several options”, if they address the question.

Comment: There is no alternate for your second and fourth examples.  Appointment doesn't make sense in the first example.  It is unclear what you mean. One doesn't conduct an appointment.  In the third example, I know what you mean, but I'd say "I'll see you at the business meeting.

Answer (score 1):

**schedule (noun)** ([Dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/schedule)

> a plan of procedure, usually written, for a proposed objective, especially with reference to the sequence of and time allotted for each item or operation necessary to its completion.

**schedule (verb)**

***to plan for a certain date*.**

> **Schedule** (verb) [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/schedule)
>
> 1. Arrange or plan (an event) to take place at a particular time.
>       *‘the release of the single is scheduled for April’*
>
> 1.1 Make arrangements for (someone or something) to do something.
>       with object and infinitive
>   *‘he is scheduled to be released from prison this spring’*

Comment: Great suggestion. I wonder why *schedule* never showed up in the thesauri. It might not be significantly shorter than *appointment*, but it’s generic and noun and verb share the same spelling.

Comment: I have the same problem as @dakab. I like the word schedule but I think it means something else: Schedule for me is the complete list of appointments, like a band is planning several gigs and all gigs together make up the schedule. But still what would be the right word for a single gig. Here schedule is not really the correct word. Maybe "date"? Not sure ...

Answer (score 0):

Merriam Webster offers you the following options but I don't think that any of them properly serves your purpose:

> Synonyms: engagement, assignation, date, rendezvous, tryst
>
> Related Words: arrangement; invitation; interview; get-together, meeting; call, visit; schedule

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/appointment)

Comment: Yeah, most dictionary entries are rather specifically synonymous or uncommon (like *assignation* or *tryst*; nice words though). One core issue of my question was the suitability of *date* as a hypernym to all what the thesaurus yields.

Comment: @dakab *a date* works in some contexts - romantic, family & informal arrangements - but not for anything of a formal nature.